# Error 1054 on Update mySQL even if table exists

Tags: mysql

here i define my code in MySQL its to update a "stock" kind of system but i keep getting the error that my table "ecomendas" does not exist even if its created multiple times. Don't know how to solve it and all i want it to do is to remove from other table that has the amount of items in stock ("encomendas" = "orders").

```
INSERT INTO encomendas (
       Encomenda_ID,
       Cliente_ID,   #ID Cliente
       Item_ID,      #ID Stock
       Unidades,     # Quantidade Ex: 100 (sacos)
       Valor_Encomenda,
       Estado_PagamentoID
)
values(
      null, #ID ENCOMENDA
      1,    #ID CLIENTE
      1,    #ID STOCK
      1,    # QUANTIDADE
      10,   #Valor Encomenda
      1     # Estado de Pagamento
);

UPDATE stock as s
SET s.Quantidade_Item = s.Quantidade_Item - encomendas.Unidades 
WHERE encomendas.Item_ID = s.Item_ID;
```

Comment: As this is only to "simulate" a database, not to really create a real database my intentions are to just "trow" a warning in a column like "status":

       SELECT ' Not enough stock ' AS ' ::          ERROR        :: ';

Just to show that the system is "tracking" the stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use a `JOIN` as below:

```
UPDATE stock as s INNER JOIN encomendas as e ON e.Item_ID = s.Item_ID
SET s.Quantidade_Item = s.Quantidade_Item - e.Unidades
```

does that do what you expect?

Comment: Yup  it works, thanks
I thought that by being inside the same query it would know that i was using the table "encomendas" but i guess i have to join them

Thank you

Comment: IF(s.Quantidade_Item > e.Unidades ,s.Quantidade_Item - e.Unidades , s.Quantidade_Item)  

I added the if so it does not let the stock go negative but it still adds to the "encomendas" table

What could i do to not let it add to the table?

Comment: @Raizan pls ask the follow-up questions properly in their own questions, not as a comment to an answer.